# From Form to JSON

Tags: json, elm

I have a HTML form which I want to turn into a JSON to send to a a server. It seems like having a simple mechanism where a the values of a form could be turned into a JSON string would be soemthing that might be in the library, so is there a library to do this?

Comment: Can you elaborate on how you created the form and how you have access to the input data from within Elm?  And maybe share a code example of the situation and the JSON string you want out of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you created the form using the [Input library](http://library.elm-lang.org/catalog/elm-lang-Elm/0.12.3/Graphics-Input), then [merge](http://library.elm-lang.org/catalog/elm-lang-Elm/0.12.3/Signal) the signals of the form Inputs into one record signal, which you can convert to JSON with [the JavaScript.Experimental API](http://library.elm-lang.org/catalog/elm-lang-Elm/0.12.3/JavaScript-Experimental).

If you created the form in HTML/JS, there is no need to delegate this task to Elm, just transform the form's DOM to your desired object representation using JavaScript.